# ORMLite Android- getting 1 column out of 17 from single table

Tags: java, android, ormlite

I have one table "company" with contains 3 columns [ name,id ,address ]. But I want to fetch only "name " column values. I am doing like this

```
Dao<Company, String> dao = getDBHelper().getCompanyDao();

QueryBuilder<Company, String> queryBuilder = dao.queryBuilder();
queryBuilder.orderBy(Company.USERNAME_FIELD_NAME, true);
**queryBuilder.selectColumns("name");**
PreparedQuery<Company> preparedQuery = queryBuilder.prepare();
CloseableIterator<Company> iterator = dao.iterator(preparedQuery);
 AndroidDatabaseResults results = (AndroidDatabaseResults) iterator.getRawResults();
Cursor cursor = results.getRawCursor();
```

But application is crashing when I add "queryBuilder.selectColumns("name") ". Please help me.I want cursor since am using cursoradapter to fill data.

crash logs are here :

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.j256.ormlite.stmt.QueryBuilder.appendFieldColumnName(QueryBuilder.java:593)
    at com.j256.ormlite.stmt.QueryBuilder.appendColumns(QueryBuilder.java:585)
    at com.j256.ormlite.stmt.QueryBuilder.appendStatementStart(QueryBuilder.java:405)
    at com.j256.ormlite.stmt.StatementBuilder.appendStatementString(StatementBuilder.java:122)
    at com.j256.ormlite.stmt.StatementBuilder.buildStatementString(StatementBuilder.java:106)
    at com.j256.ormlite.stmt.StatementBuilder.prepareStatement(StatementBuilder.java:74)
    at com.j256.ormlite.stmt.QueryBuilder.prepare(QueryBuilder.java:98)
```

Comment: What version of ORMLite are you using?

Comment: I am using ormlite-core-4.45.jar and ormlite-android-4.45.jar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But application is crashing when I add "queryBuilder.selectColumns("name")

Wow.  This is a very subtle and long standing bug.  It will happen whenever you try to select columns from an entity that does not have an ID field.  I've added this bug report:

> https://sourceforge.net/p/ormlite/bugs/162/

This has been fixed in trunk and will be in 4.49.  Here's the check-in.

> https://github.com/j256/ormlite-core/commit/ee95883040a3618a1d455b44f6bfd6935a8d4ec7